# Unable to Scroll to Bottom of List in a MAUI Application

Tags: .net, view, scroll, maui

Context: I'm working on a mobile application that tracks the programs performed by a user each day.

Problem: I'm experiencing an issue where, upon clicking on a user's profile and viewing their program history, I cannot scroll down to the bottom of the list if the user has completed a large number of programs.

Here is my implementation:

-> **View (Program History):**

Code modified by the first solution (but impossible to scroll to the bottom of the list)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ProjetSport.Views.ExerciceActivitiesView"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ProjetSport.ViewModels"
             Title="ExerciceActivitiesView">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:ActiviteExerciceViewModel></vm:ActiviteExerciceViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.BackgroundColor>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="#FEFAE2" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="#FEFAE2" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="#FEFAE2" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.BackgroundColor>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0">
            <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,20,0,20">
                <Label Text="Vous avez effectué : "></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Avancee}" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                <Label Text="%" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                <Label Text=" du programme selectionné"></Label>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
            <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Border Stroke="#000000"
            StrokeThickness="5"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 50,50,50,50"
            BackgroundColor="#DFDBC6"
            HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Button Text="Afficher les exercices" Clicked="Button_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="#FEF8BF" TextColor="#000000"></Button>
                </Border>
                <Border Stroke="#000000"
            StrokeThickness="5"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 50,50,50,50"
            BackgroundColor="#DFDBC6"
            HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Button Text="Réduire" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="#FEF8BF" TextColor="#000000"></Button>
                </Border>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="1"
                WidthRequest="350"
                x:Name="CollectionView"
                IsVisible="true"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Exercices}"
             BackgroundColor="#FEFAE2"
             ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedProgramActivity}"
            />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

-> **Code-behind :**

```
public partial class ExerciceActivitiesView : ContentPage
{
    public ExerciceActivitiesView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionView.IsVisible = true;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionView.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

-> **DataTemplate**

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="Activite">
                <Border Stroke="#000000" StrokeThickness="3" BackgroundColor="#F2EED5" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10, 20, 20, 10" Margin="0,10,5,20">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="50,20,0,20">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="Small"
                               Margin="-10,0,0,0"
                               TextColor="#100905"
                    ></Label>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="240,15,0,0">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="Small"
                               Margin="-10,0,0,0"
                               TextColor="#100905"
                            />
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to fix this scrolling issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be more specific than "cannot scroll".  Can you scroll at all?  Does it work then stop scrolling at some point?  What is the threshhold at which it stops working?

Comment: @Jason Scrolling is functional, but due to the large number of programs, I'm unable to reach the bottom of the list

Comment: If you keep VerticalStackLayout, but remove everything else in it except the CollectionView, does it work? If that still has problem, then if you remove VerticalStackLayout, does it work? Goal is to find out what exact situation does not work.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I can display up to four programs, but starting from the fifth one, I encounter issues with scrolling. When I attempt to scroll to view the fifth program, I can briefly see it as I scroll down, but then the list automatically scrolls back up on its own.

Comment: Add to question XAML of ItemTemplate. And try the test without VerticalStackLayout or other elements.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve one program = one line

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I just added you the data template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253805/discussion-between-eloi-jahan-and-toolmakersteve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this to allow scrolling of your data if you have a lot of it

```
   <ContentPage.BackgroundColor>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="#FEFAE2" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="#FEFAE2" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="#FEFAE2" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.BackgroundColor>
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
          
            <!-- The code of your project  -->
           
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for Steve's effort. You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Comment: Note that this is not advised, if "The code of your project" contains a `CollectionView`. Replace any nested CollectionView with a [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout). This can be another `VerticalStackLayout` that has a `<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>`. REASON: CollectionView has its own scrolling. Putting one scrollable layout inside another often results in difficulty scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

This should help, if Maui is having some issue with CollectionView inside VerticalStackLayout. Move CollectionView into its own Grid Row, and give it all remaining space `*`:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
   <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0">
      ... all your xaml EXCEPT CollectionView ...
   </VerticalStackLayout>
   <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ...>
      ...
   </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is a solution that can work. Thanks to you.
Finally, I modified the view that I show in another solution and that I use with the scroll view.